# Ajax get questions by tags ERROR

Tags: support, documentation, questions, api-key, jsonp

i'm trying getting questions by tags.

this is my simple code and i'm running this from my `http://localhost`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url:'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=php&page=1&pagesize=15',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    type:'GET',
    error:function(e){
   console.log(e);
    },
    beforeSend:function(){

    },
    success: function(data){
 data = JSON.parse(data);
  $.each(data,function(e){
  $("#wrapper").append(data[e].total);
  });

  }
 });
  });
</script>
```

then i receive an error in console:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label

"total": 2000,

search...8184757 (line 2, col 2)
```

seems the error is generated by the json returned format, cause "total" is a result key.

how can i fix this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one use the [current API version (2.1)](http://api.stackexchange.com/) instead of an old one (1.1 in your case).

Furthermore, when using JSONP you do not have to parse the result. The data object you get in your `success` method already is a JavaScript object you can work with.

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?page=1&pagesize=15&tagged=php&site=stackoverflow',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    type:'GET',
    error:function(e){
      console.log(e);
    },
    success: function(data){
      // do something with the result here    
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The API expects JSONP requests to specify the callback as the [`jsonp` parameter](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage), not the `callback` that jQuery uses by default.

While really you should consider upgrading to [API 2.1](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), which *does* expect `callback` (and allows [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), for that matter), you can fix your code by putting in the `jsonp` parameter placeholder:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?jsonp=?&tagged=php&page=1&pagesize=15',
// ...                                            ^-- this
```

Also, you don't need to call `JSON.parse()` on the response data, since it will be an object already.